# Laver's Proof that $V$ and $V[G]$ have the $\delta$-approximation property.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $V$ be a transitive model of ZFC, $\mathbb{P} \in V$ be a forcing poset such that $(|\mathbb{P}| < \delta)^{V}$ for some regular cardinal $\delta$ in $V$, and $G$ be a $V$-generic filter over $\mathbb{P}$. I wish to show that $\langle V, V[G]\rangle$ has the $\delta$-approximation property. That is, for every $X \in V[G]$ such that $X \subset V$, if $Y \cap X \in V$ for every $Y \in V$ with $(|Y| < \delta)^V$, then $X \in V$.

In "Certain very large cardinals are not created in small forcing extensions" (page 3), Laver gives the following argument.

Let $A$ be a set of ordinals in $V[G] \setminus V$. In $V$, we define $B$ as follows.

$$B = \{\alpha : \text{for some } r\in \mathbb{P}, \alpha \text{ is the least ordinal such that for some forcing conditions } p , q > r, p \Vdash \alpha \in A \land q \Vdash \alpha \notin A\}$$

$B$ must be nonempty (otherwise $A$ is definable in $V$) and have size $<\delta$. Then Laver claims that $B\cap A \notin V$. **My first question** is that I don't understand why $B\cap A \notin V$. It'd appreciated if anyone could explain it in detail.

**My second question** is: why does it suffice to show that $\delta$-approximation holds for sets of ordinals in $V[G]$? I attempt to show this by using the fact that every set is coded by a set of ordinals. So let $X \in V[G] \setminus V$ with $X\subset V$ be an arbitrary set coded by a set of ordinals $A \in V[G]\setminus V$. Then by the argument above, there must be some small set $B \in V$ such that $B \cap A \notin V$. But how do we know $B \cap A$ codes a small set of $X$?

Comment: I don't know why this has a vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, note that for any $r\in G$, there is $\alpha\in B$ that "comes from $r$". For any such $\alpha$, $G$ has "generically decided" whether to put $\alpha$ into $A$ or not and this makes sure that $B\cap A\notin V$. For suppose $C\in V$ is a set of ordinals. Then for any $r\in G$ there is $\alpha\in B$ and some $p\leq r$ so that
$$p\Vdash\check\alpha\in A\Leftrightarrow\alpha\notin C$$
This is a density argument that shows that there must be some $r', p'\in G$ and some $\alpha'\in B$ that "comes from $r'$" so that
$$p'\Vdash\alpha'\in A\Leftrightarrow \alpha'\notin C$$
and hence $B\cap A\neq C$.

For the second question, use the following trick: Since $X\subseteq V$, there is some $Y\in V$ with $X\subseteq Y$. Any $V_\alpha$ with $\alpha$ large enough works. Now in $V$ (!) code $Y$ as a set of ordinals, actually any bijection
$$\pi:Y\rightarrow \gamma$$
for an ordinal $\gamma$ is fine. Now replace $X$ by $X'=\pi[X]$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I still got two questions. First, I can see that for any $r \in G$, there must be some $p \in G$ below $r$ and $\alpha$ such that $p \Vdash \alpha \in A \leftrightarrow \alpha \notin C$. But how do we find such $\alpha$ in $B$? Second, can you explain more about the density argument? Are we showing this set $D =\{p : \exists \alpha \in B p \Vdash \alpha \in A \leftrightarrow \alpha \notin C\} $ is dense?

Comment: Yes exactly, you have to show that $D$ is dense (or that $D$ is dense below a condition $s\in G$ that forces $A\notin V$ to be precise). If $r\leq s$ then there is $\alpha$ in $B$ that "comes from $r$" and thus there is $p\leq r$ with $p\Vdash\alpha\in A\Leftrightarrow \alpha\notin C$.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the last sentence? I didn't quite follow. Why are there such $\alpha \in B$ and $p$?

Comment: Sure! As $r\Vdash A\notin V$ there must be some $\beta$ so that $r$ does not decide whether or not $\beta\in A$, that is there are $p, q \leq r$ with $p\Vdash\beta\in A$ and $q\Vdash\beta\notin A$. (Otherwise $A$ would be definable in $V$) Now let $\alpha$ be the minimal such $\beta$. Then $\alpha\in B$ and there is $p\leq r$ with $p\Vdash\alpha\in A\Leftrightarrow\alpha\notin C$.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience. But I'm still confused. Did you mean "there are $p, q > r$" in your last comment, given Laver's definition of $B$?

Comment: Im sorry, I just noticed you are using the Israel convention that $p$ is a stronger forcing condition than $q$ is written $q\leq p$, while I would write $p\leq q$. So just flip all my $\leq$'s :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot! I think it's just a typo in the paper--it is never stated that the Israel convention is being used. Gosh, this thing almost killed me. Is this argument a standard trick in forcing? I wish it were explained in the paper. Anyways, really appreciate your help!